# Dynamically compiling and mounting elements with VueJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, vue.js, vuejs2

### The Issue

I've created a light-weight wrapper around jQuery DataTables for VueJS like so:

```
<template>
    <table ref="table" class="display table table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th v-for="(column, index) in columns">
                    {{ column.name }}
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['columns', 'url'],
        mounted: function () {
            $(this.$refs.table).dataTable({
                ajax: this.url,
                columns: this.columns
            });
            // Add any elements created by DataTable
            this.$compile(this.$refs.table);
        }
    }
</script>
```

I'm utilizing the data table like so:

```
<data-table
    :columns="
        [
            {
                name: 'County',
                data: 'location.county',
            },
            {
                name: 'Acres',
                data: 'details.lot_size',
            },
            {
                name: 'Price',
                data: 'details.price',
                className: 'text-xs-right',
            },
            {
                name: 'Actions',
                data: null,
                render: (row) => {
                    return &quot;\
                        <a @click='editProperty' class='btn btn-warning'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Edit</a>\
                    &quot;;
                }
            },
        ]
    "
    url="/api/properties"
></data-table>
```

Note the "render" method for the Actions column. This function runs just fine and renders the button as expected, however the `@click` handler is not functional.

Looking around I've found two links which were not helpful:

[Issue 254 on the VueJS GitHub repo](https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/254) provides a solution for VueJS 1.0 (using `this.$compile`) however this was removed in VueJS 2.0

[A blog post by Will Vincent](https://willvincent.com/blog/making-vuejs-and-datatables-play-nice) discusses how to make the DataTable re-render when local data changes dynamically, but doesn't provide a solution for attaching handlers to the rendered elements

### Minimum Viable Solution

If the rendered element can't be compiled and mounted, that would alright so long as I could run methods of the `DataTable` component on-click. Perhaps something like:

```
render: (row) => {
    return &quot;\
        <a onclick='Vue.$refs.MyComponent.methods.whatever();' />\
    &quot;;
}
```

Is there any such way to call methods from outside of the Vue context?

Comment: For handing events in a render function, you use the [`on:` section](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth) of `createElement`. Not so template-y.

Comment: @RoyJ I don't immediately see how I could use the `on:` section to handle an event thrown by a child created after my component is mounted. At best maybe I could listen for `nativeOn:` and react to the event after it bubbled up, then try to use `e.target` to figure out where the event came from, but that sounds subject to breaking. Could you give an example of what you're suggesting?

Comment: I think I was just misunderstanding where your render function came into play.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This meets your minimum viable solution.

In your columns definition:

```
render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
   return `<span class="edit-placeholder">Edit</span>`  
}
```

And in your DataTable component:

```
methods:{
  editProperty(data){
    console.log(data)
  }
},
mounted: function() {
  const table = $(this.$refs.table).dataTable({
    ajax: this.url,
    columns: this.columns
  });

  const self = this
  $('tbody', this.$refs.table).on( 'click', '.edit-placeholder', function(){
      const cell = table.api().cell( $(this).closest("td") );
      self.editProperty(cell.data())
  });
}
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/VbPZYq?editors=1010) (uses a different API, but the same idea).

This is using jQuery, but you're already using jQuery so it doesn't feel that terrible.

I played some games trying to get a component to mount in the `render` function of the data table with some success, but I'm not familiar enough with the DataTable API to make it work completely. The biggest issue was the DataTable API expects the render function to return a string, which is... limiting. The API also *very irritatingly* doesn't give you a reference to the cell you are currently in, which seems obvious. Otherwise you could do something like

```
render(columnData){
   const container = document.createElement("div")
   new EditComponent({data: {columnData}).$mount(container)
   return container
}
```

Also, the render function is called with multiple modes. I was able to render a component into the cell, but had to play a lot of games with the mode, etc. [This is an attempt](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/BRpNLN?editors=1010), but it has several issues. I'm linking it to give you an idea what I was trying. Maybe you will have more success.

Finally, you *can* mount a component onto a placeholder rendered by DataTable. Consider this component.

```
const Edit = Vue.extend({
  template: `<a @click='editProperty' class='btn btn-warning'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Edit</a>`,
  methods:{
    editProperty(){
      console.log(this.data.name)
      this.$emit("edit-property")
    }
  }
});
```

In your mounted method you could do this:

```
mounted: function() {
  const table = $(this.$refs.table).dataTable({
    ajax: this.url,
    columns: this.columns
  });

  table.on("draw.dt", function(){
    $(".edit-placeholder").each(function(i, el){
        const data = table.api().cell( $(this).closest("td") ).data();
        new Edit({data:{data}}).$mount(el)
    })
  })
```

}

This will render a Vue on top of each placeholder, and re-render it when it is drawn. [Here](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/BRpNPL?editors=1010) is an example of that.

Comment: I'll have to test this tonight when I'm back from work, but preliminary reading it looks brilliant! Going to go ahead and give a +1 for all the hard work, and will mark as correct if it runs tonight :)

Comment: I actually extended your solution just **slightly**. Because my DataTable component is intended to be generic, I didn't want the "edit property" logic to be in the DataTable component. So I had it `this.$emit("draw")` on the `dt.draw` event, then I placed the code for mounting a new `Edit` component in the component that actually utilized the DataTable for displaying properties